# Insert \double value with doctrine in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a class called Plato that extends Producto witch contains de atribute precio. The setter is defined here:

```
public function setPrecio(\double $precio)
{
   $this->precio = $precio;

   return $this;
}
```

And I trying to add a new element to the DB with:

```
$plato = new Plato; 
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
 // I have tryed this three ways to insert
$plato->SetPrecio(doubleval($precio));  
$plato->SetPrecio((double) 2);
$plato->SetPrecio(2.0);

$em->flush();
```

It gives me the following error message:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Servinow\EntitiesBundle\Entity\Producto::setPrecio() must be an
>   instance of double, double given, called in
>   /Users/luis/git/servinowServer-luis/src/Servinow/EntitiesBundle/Entity/PlatoRepository.php
>   on line 41 and defined in
>   /Users/luis/git/servinowServer-luis/src/Servinow/EntitiesBundle/Entity/Producto.php
>   line 169

Comment: I was messing around trying to think of a way to help, and I discovered this behavior in php `echo gettype(9.4); var_dump(9.4);` and now my mind hurts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify `setPrecio()` function in that way

```
public function setPrecio($precio)
{
   $this->precio = $precio;

   return $this;
}
```

You could use something like that

```
gettype($precio)[...];
if(is_numeric($precio))[...];
```

for type control, before set it into `$this`

Remember that

> Type Hints can only be of the object and array (since PHP 5.1) type.
>   Traditional type hinting with int and string isn't supported.

Comment: +1 You could also throw an `if (is_numeric)` in there too to make sure

Comment: @Dale I was updating while you were writing your comment

Comment: @user1403186 if the question resolve your problem, please check it and accept it as the corret answer. Thank you